# Installing IIS on a Sever 2003 VM

Tags: iis, windows-server-2003, virtual-machine

I want to install IIS on a WIN Server 2003 Virtual Machine. I set this VM up via a VHD file and I do not have Windows CD or its ISO. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't install IIS without the Windows Server ISO, CD, or the i386 directory on the CD/DVD. Try to see if a copy of the CD/DVD is somewhere on your network. You can point to the i386 directory and install IIS, if it's located somewhere.

Comment: Also an x64 directory for the 64-bit version, but I assume you have 32-bit 2003 installed.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the CD is not needed, as the I386 folder is on hard drive under c:\Windows\I386. 
You will need to point to it 3 or 4 times but it works.

Comment: On the 2003 image provided by Microsoft (as a VHD image), I used the "C:\Windows Installation Files\I386" path.